# Select Case to handle active TabPage

Tags: vb.net

A program with a Form and a TabControl. I need to handle what happens when the user close the form according to the active TabControlPage

Is working with If - Then like this

```
If PanelChooserTabControl.SelectedTab Is SelectionTabPage Then
    'What I want
End If

If PanelChooserTabControl.SelectedTab Is EditionTabPage Then
    'The user can´t leave
    e.Cancel = True
End If
```

But I will have more TabPages and I want to make the code easy with Select Case

```
Dim TabPageActive As String = PanelChooserTabControl.SelectedTab.ToString
Select Case TabPageActive
    Case "TabPage:{SelectionTabPage}"
        'What I want
    Case "EditionTabPage"
        'What I want
End Select
```

But the TabPageActive variable is loaded with something like 
TabPage:{SelectionTabPage}

and not only "SelectionTabPage". Even using TabPage:{SelectionTabPage} as the Case variable (like the example code) is not working.

**Do I need to make another string conversion or trim?**

Comment: Why not switch on `SelectedIndex` instead?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Because a number is less descriptive than the text. Thanks for the tip

Comment: So add a comment.  You were using strings anyway so a comment is just as good.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Logic! I make another version using SelectedIndex and worked fine too. Another thing I learn! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Select Case True
  Case PanelChooserTabControl.SelectedTab Is SelectionTabPage
  Case PanelChooserTabControl.SelectedTab Is EditionTabPage
  ...
End Select
```

or on tabPage index change save as an enum the page and use this enum in the case.

Comment: You probably ought to provide examples of the cases as it may not be obvious.

Comment: I've accidentally post the answer before finished. ;-)

Comment: @shadow Your solution was what I needed... and really simple. First time I read about using Select Case True. Thanks.